# if and else statement logic confusion

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I am new to Java and I am practicing doing a java application that loops to ask the user some inputs regarding some items that this person has sold. but I am trying to make my condition of the if statement according to my menu option.. so, if the user inputs something like -1 or any negative number or out of range number this will be grater than 4 the if statement will fail and show the error message that is followed in the else statement. but some how I am missing something that I can't see, so I hope someone of you guys can actually see it and let me know what I am missing..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        SalesCal a = new SalesCal();

        int select = 1; // menu selection
        int solds; // sales person input

         a.displayMessage();

        while(select != 0){

            System.out.print("Plese enter \t1 for item1($239.99),\n\t\t2 for item2($129.75),\n\t\t3 for item3($99.95),\n\t\t4 for item4($350.89),\n\t\t0 to cancel: ");
            select = input.nextInt(); //getting user input
            System.out.print("\n");

            if((select <= 4) && (select <= 0) && (select < 0)){
                System.out.printf("You selected: item%d\n", select);
                System.out.printf("Plese enter the quantity sold for item%d: ", select);
                solds = input.nextInt(); //getting user input
                System.out.print("\n");
                a.GrossCal(select, solds);
            } else {
                System.err.print("Wrong selectiong, please try again...\n\n");
            }   
        }
        a.displayResults();
    }

}
```

Thanks I will really appreciate it your help...

Comment: Which number is smaller than 4 and 0 at the same time?

Comment: never thought about it, I will try.. its my first time using netbeans and coding in java.. but deff will check it out

Comment: Next time, tell us what answer you expected and what input you used.

Comment: @zapl it supposed to between 1-4 and 0 for cancel.. negative or out of range numbers like -5 or 6 will execute the error message

Comment: @Infinity I think, I tried to explain what I am trying to do within the post if not clear, my bad. english is not my first language but I tried my best.

Comment: if ((select >= 0) && (select <= 4))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the `if` statement logic you want is:

```
if (select > 0 && select <= 4){
    System.out.printf("You selected: item%d\n", select);
    System.out.printf("Plese enter the quantity sold for item%d: ", select);
    solds = input.nextInt(); //getting user input
    System.out.print("\n");
    a.GrossCal(select, solds);
} else if (select != 0) {
    System.err.print("Wrong selectiong, please try again...\n\n");
}
```

This skips both the processing logic and the error message when the user enters 0.

Comment: it seems to work better your way but leaving the else statement by itself, but when I press 0 stills shows the error message from the else statement which I don't get

Comment: actually works but I feel like netbeans is being kinda retarded with the printing of the message.. thanks tho..

Comment: @NorthBlast - I'm glad it worked for you. The idea with my code was to skip the request for quantity when the user entered 0. That's why the first `if` has `select > 0` instead of `select >= 0`. However, since 0 is a valid input (meaning "quit"), I also needed the `else if` part so the error message wasn't displayed.

Answer (score 4):

`if((select <= 4) && (select >= 0))`, this statement should take care of -ve input

Answer (score 2):

```
if((select <= 4) && (select <= 0) && (select < 0))

         A                B                C
```

is exactly the same as

```
if(select < 0)

      D
```

Think about it:

- If `select` is 5: A,B,C and D all fail (result in `false`). Both ifs return `false`.
- If it's 4: B, C, and D fail. Both ifs return `false`.
- If it's 1: B, C, and D fail. Both ifs return `false`.
- If it's 0: C and D fail. Both return `false`.
- If it's -1: A, B, C, and D all succeed (return `true`). Both ifs return `true`.

But if you want less than zero or *greater* than four to be considered as bad, which is what I think you mean, then you want

```
if(select < 0  ||  select > 4)
```

If zero and four are also bad themselves, then use

```
if(select <= 0  ||  select => 4)
```

or

```
if(!(select > 0  &&  select < 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have one extra handlebar at the very end.

One way to determine which if and else belongs to is find the inner most if. The closest else to this is the else related to the if. You can work outwards from there.

:D

or you could use a switch statement and enter in your own logic if the condition is true:

```
switch(select) { 
    case 0: System.out.println("select = 0");
    break;
    case 1: System.out.println("select = 1"); 
    break;
    case 2: System.out.println("select = 2");
    break;
    case 3: System.out.println("select = 3");
    break;
    case 4: System.out.println("select = 4");
    break;
    default: System.out.println("Please enter a number from zero to four");


}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome. :D ...nested if/else statements are confusing. If brackets are used this can change the meaning of the code to use an else statement not closes to the if I think. If the statements are not bracketed then the closest inner else to the closest inner if works as a way to figure out the code logic. :D It just takes some practice and you will have it.